# Wordpress - CSS styling not applying on a row

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm currently building a site on Wordpress using the html5blank as the parent theme. I've built all the front-end text pages on HTMl/CSS. When I've transferred all the files over a lot of the styling has broken - I've fixed the majority of it but there's one section that I cannot fix. This is how it should look -

[image: Front-end version]

And this is how it looks in the Wordpress site -

[image: Wordpress version]

When I've inspected the site via developer tools it seems as though these rules are not being applied -

```
.agencyproducts {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;

}
```

Also, the row in the front-end site is applying a height rule but not in the wordpress site. I've looked at applying specificity rules and !important but nothing (this also disrupts other styling rules on other parts of the site). I'm really stuck on this and would appreciate any assistance.

Here's the full code for the section -

```css
section#products {
 height: 800px;
 max-width: 100%
}

.agencyproducts {
 position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
   text-align: center;
}

.agencyproducts p {
 text-align: center;
 margin: 30px;
}

.agencyproducts img {
 width: 70px;
 height: 70px;
 position: relative;
   line-height: 1;
   top: 50%;
}

figure {
   text-align: center;
   display: inline-block;
    max-width: 80px;
    height: 100px;
   vertical-align: top;
   margin: 5px;
   font-size: 9px;
   margin-bottom: 60px;
   
}

figure img {
 padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.four {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 border: 0;
}

.images {
 margin-top: 30px;
 border-bottom: 10px;
}

.images img {
 margin-left: 20px;
 padding: 10px;
 
}

.chevron {
 height: 150px;
}

.chevron figcaption {
 margin-top: 20px;
 font-size: 13px;
 color: #d3d3d3;

 
}

hr.hragency {
  display: block;
  width: 250px;
  margin-top: 0em;
  margin-bottom: 0em;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-style: inset;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #F0F0F0;
}
```

```html
<section id="products">
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="twelve columns agencyproducts">
            <p>WHAT PRODUCT ARE YOU INTERESTED IN?</p>
            <a href="2k4kproduction.html">
                <figure>
                    <img src="images/production.png" alt="Production">
                    <figcaption>2K / 4K PRODUCTION</figcaption>
                </figure>
            </a>
            <a href="postproduction.html">
                <figure> 
                    <img src="images/post-production.png" alt="Post-Production">
                    <figcaption>POST PRODUCTION</figcaption>
                </figure>
            </a>
            <a href="2d3danimation.html">
                <figure>
                    <img src="images/animation.png" alt="Animation">
                    <figcaption>2D / 3D ANIMATION</figcaption>
                </figure>
            </a>
            <a href="adhoc.html"><figure> 
                <img src="images/ADHOC.png" alt="ADHOC">
                <figcaption>ADHOC</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </a>
        <a href="interactive.html">
            <figure> 
                <img src="images/interactive.png" alt="Interactive">
                <figcaption>INTERACTIVE & PERSONALISED</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </a>
        <a href="tvadverts.html">
            <figure>
                <img src="images/tv-adverts.png" alt="TV ADVERTS">
                <figcaption>TV ADVERTS</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </a>
        <a href="360video.html"><figure> 
            <img src="images/360.png" alt="360 Video and VR">
            <figcaption>360 VIDEO & VIRTUAL REALITY</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </a>  
</div>
</div>   
<hr class="hragency">
<div class="row">
<div class="images">
    <div class="four columns">
        <img src="images/VIDEO.jpg" alt="Video">
        <img src="images/blog.jpg" alt="blog">
    </div>
    <div class="four columns"> 
        <img src="images/faq.jpg" alt="FAQ">
        <img src="images/VIDEO.jpg" alt="Video">
    </div>
    <div class="four columns"> 
        <img src="images/blog.jpg" alt="blog">
        <img src="images/faq.jpg" alt="FAQ">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>            
<section class="chevron">
<div class="container">                
    <div class="row">
        <figure>
            <figcaption>SEE MORE</figcaption>
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </figure>
    </div>       
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Is your stylesheet loaded at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
.agencyproducts{
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}

.agencyproducts a{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Because container `.agencyproducts` need to have `text-align:center` and first childs of it must be displayed as `inline-block` ... then they will display properly. You only set child of `a` tag as `display:inline-block` but do not tell CSS how it should treat it parent.

Comment: Yes to this answer. You've added display:inline-block to "figure" but that is itself wrapped in "a" tags. It's those "a" tags you want to inline-block.

Comment: @Michael Why does this work in my front-end static site but not in my wordpress site?

Comment: Did You try my answer ? If yes and its still do not work then this rules must be overwritten somewhere ... put in function.php wp_enqueue_style( 'your-css-with-this-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/css/your-css.css', 'all' ); at bottom after all other stylesheets.

Comment: @Michael Is it worth putting that code in my functions.php file anyway? Just so all my styles override everything - full stop. I'm really frustrated at the amount of digging I'm having to do with this site for specificity and I really don't want to use !important if I don't have to. What is the full script for this?

Comment: hard to explain :) CSS file in which You add Your changes for sure is enqueue in Your function.php because thats how WordPress work with CSS. Sometimes Your changes can be override by some later CSS ... But if this work, don't change anything in function.php ... !important is not a solution, I use !important only in media queries to force change on mobiles.

Answer (score 0):

With what I understood try appending `!important` to your custom css properties so as to override any pre-existing style properties.

```
height: 150px !important;
```

Comment: If you need to use `!important`, that means you already done something wrong. Bad advice

Comment: Totally agree and upvoted. You *can* use !important for debugging CSS. Or late on a Friday when you wanna go home.